# app crashes when loaded from Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

After I have exported my app and loaded to Google Play, I get crashes when app starts. But, when I load it from Eclipse, everything is fine. I have no clue what the problem could be:

Log Cat:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mytaxicontrol/com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mytaxicontrol.MyTaxiControlActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.mytaxicontrol-3.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.mytaxicontrol-3, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2340)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mytaxicontrol" 
android:versionCode="1083"
android:versionName="3.0.6">
<uses-permission android:name="com.mytaxicontrol.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>


 <permission
    android:name="com.mytaxicontrol.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />



    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:allowBackup="true">
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIz...................."/>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />



<meta-data    
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
        android:value=".search" />

<service android:name="BillingService" />
   <activity android:name=".MyTaxiControlActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop"

android:label="myTaxi Control"  
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category   android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity android:name=".Instructions" android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Tariffs" android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Taxis" android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">


    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Preferences" android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>
<activity android:name=".InApp" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:label="@string/app_name">

    </activity>


</application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: I think it is about a external library ?

Comment: Have you renamed your package or something like that? Could you make your apk you uploaded accessable, so I can have a look on your manifest?

Comment: I havent renamed the package and there are no new external libraries added to the project since the previous upload that worked fine. How would I make the apk accessible in SO? Will post the Manifest in a few minutes.

Comment: Nobody having an idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: The damage starts to get substantial. I have frustrated users who cant use the app at all. Is it possible that Eclipse went mad and I should completely reinstall Eclipse? I have now removed app from Google Play to avoid futher damnage. Can I rollback the app version in GP to a known working version? I have recreated the apk and uploaded again, but still the same. I am ready to offer a bounty to anyone helping out, but I cant wait 2 days until I am allowed to offer the boundy. HELP!!!!

Answer (score 0):

json jar was missing in the Build path. Why on earth doesnt Eclipse send a meaningful error message? Our life as developer could be so much easier.